# Why is string shortened when manually setting bytes with memset?

Tags: c

I'm working on a project in which i need to create a string of arbitrary length and set all the characters to a specific character.

Example of setting bytes:

```
char str[i];
memset(str, '*', i);
str[i] = '\0';
```

This seems to work so far, however when I change the last line to `str[i + 1] = '\0';`, my output is being shortened by one.

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Comment: `str[i + 1]` isn’t in bounds. `str[i]` isn’t either. You declared the array as having `i` elements with indexes from `0` to `i - 1` inclusive.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Please note that doing `int i = 42; char str[i];` makes use of the language element called "Variable Length Arrays", which is available form C99 on only, and had become *optional* with C11. (Also VLAs are not supported by C++ at all),

Comment: if you need "a string of arbitrary length" then use `malloc`, don't use [VLA](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array#Variable-length_arrays) which is very dangerous unless you can be sure that the string is always small enough to not result in stack overflow

Answer (score 1):

```
str[i] = '\0';
```

and

```
str[i + 1] = '\0';
```

are undefined behaviour because C language does not checking array bound.

C11 standard :

> **J.2 Undefined behavor**
>
> - An array subscript is out of range, even if an object is apparently accessible with the given subscript (as in the lvalue expression
>     a[1][7] given the declaration int a[4][5]) (6.5.6).

Answer (score 1):

With `str[i]` and `str[i + 1]` you are accessing outside the bounds of `str`. This is [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

If you need `i` length of data (excluding the terminating null byte), your array `str` has to have space for `i + 1` elements in order to accommodate the null terminator.

On the other hand, if you are not using `str` as a C-string (e.g., using any of the standard C library functions that expect a null terminated strings), then you don't need to null terminate it at all.